# permissions to allow role to edit the posted date

Tags: users

in drupal 7 - I have given a role the permissions to edit, add delete and modify content but he doesn't see the authored date in order to modify it.  how can I give him permissions to modify that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated date is set automatically by the system, if you want to edit that you will need to write some custom code.  Your user *should* be able to see the 'authored date' though.

Alternatively, if you need a date field that the user can edit (say, a publication date), just create a [date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) field on your content and render it appropriately.

---

[edit based on additional info]:

I went digging in the code and found this in node.pages.inc:

```
$form['author'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#access' => user_access('administer nodes'),
  '#title' => t('Authoring information'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#group' => 'additional_settings',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('node-form-author'),
  ),
  '#attached' => array(
    'js' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'node') . '/node.js',
      array(
        'type' => 'setting',
        'data' => array('anonymous' => variable_get('anonymous', t('Anonymous'))),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  '#weight' => 90,
);
```

As you can see, access is tied to the 'administer nodes' permission which I'm guessing you haven't, and probably don't want to give to that role.

Luckily this is quite easy to change using `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`, [here's the API for that function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7).

Create a custom module and put this in it:

```
function MODULENAME_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

    // You may wish to add some logic here to test for a specific role

    $form['author']['#access'] = TRUE;

    // Otherwise this will simply give everyone who can create nodes the
    // ability to change author and date.

}
```

Comment: Hi, that is the date I want him to see (the authored date) but it's not visible to him (I can see it when I edit as an admin though)

Comment: Updated answer.